# How do I put the value of check boxes in a textbox when i click a command button?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm quite new in using VBA Userforms. I have a series of check boxes and I want to put the value of the ticked checkboxes inside a text box when I click a command button. I have already renamed the check boxes and when I enter a code/formula I'm encountering an error. I hope you can help me with this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Call Level1

End Sub

Sub Level1()

    Dim n As Long
    For n = 26 To 89
        'UserForm1.Controls("CheckBox" & n) = False

    Next
    Dim i As Long, txt As String
    For i = 1 To 3

        **If UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & i) = True Then** (Error Here)
            txt = txt & UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & i).Caption & ", "

        End If
    Next

    txt = Left(txt, Len(txt) - 2)
    'Cells(1, 1) = txt
    TextBox1.Value = txt

End Sub
```

My Userform looks like this.

[When I click the Add to QA Form, the values that I ticked should be entered in the textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npMXe.jpg)

Is there anyway that this can be simplified? I have other check boxes that I need to enter and they are more than 50. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Stacy, can you add to your question the text of the "error" you're seeing? I think that `UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & i) = True` is maybe giving you an error, because you are comparing `Control` to `Boolean`. Are you trying to check if the control exists? Maybe try `If Not UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & i) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question so that it includes the specific error you're encountering (and where), and make the title about that specific problem - that way people googling similar problems will land here and find an answer (once it's answered, obviously). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: Right... VBA. Comment edited.

Comment: Thanks for the advise guys. I already edited my question. I also tried using the If Not UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & i) Is Nothing Then but it also did not work.

Comment: I think Just adding “.value”  (i.e. If UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & i) .Value = True Then) will make it work. Also better to wrap it with “If Not UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & i) Is Nothing Then” as suggested by @cory